# Autoit click button by value

Tags: html, button, click, autoit

I want to click this butoon:

```
<input type="button" value="Click me" id="ext-gen1133">
```

but the problem is that **id changes after every refresh**, so I can use _IEGetObjById. I've been serching for solution for few hours but nothing's working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

If the value remains the same each time, you can loop through to find the button  with the value that you want:

```
$oButtons = _IETagnameGetCollection($oIE, "button")
For $oButton in $oButtons
    If String($oButton.value) = "click me" Then
        _IEAction($oButton, "click")
        ExitLoop
    EndIf
Next
```